# Calculating levels of loan default over a time series

Tags: python, pandas

I am calculating different levels of default in a loan book over time. I calculate default as: 
`amount_of_money_due_to_be_paid` - `amount_of_money_actually_paid`

```
id  amount  due_date    paid y/n
1   1000    2017-01-01    no
2   1000    2017-02-01    yes
3   1000    2017-03-01    no
4   1000    2017-04-01    no
5   1000    2017-05-01    yes
```

I need to calculate this at different levels of default, i.e. `30 days_past_due`, `60 days_past_due` etc over a time series. As of the last day in each month, I need to know how much money was more than x days overdue. (E.g. As of June 30, how much money was more than 15 days past due)

Therefore I need to divide `amount_of_money_actually_paid` / `amount_money_due_to_be_paid_up_to_15_days_ago`

The resulting dataframe would have the last date of each month listed as each column header, and the rows would be the `default_%` at each date in the column header.

```
Date:      2017-01-31  2017-02-29  2017-03-31  2017-04-30  2017-05-31  
Default %:    100%         50%       66.67%        25%          40%
```

In Excel, I calculate the denominator by summing the amount of money with `due_date` before the column header less x number of days (i.e. sum the amounts, if the due_date is before e.g. [(2017-03-31 - 15 days) = 2017-03-16]

I need help in calculating this in Python.

I have done the below analysis for another part of my code, and I think a small change could fix the issue.

```
def default_days(date, outstanding_loans, days):
    m = (outstanding_loans['repayment_date'] <= date - pd.DateOffset(days))
    c = sum(m)
    return c

dates = pd.date_range('2015-11-30',pd.to_datetime('today'), freq='M')

defaultt = pd.DataFrame({'date':dates})

defaultt['15 days'] = defaultt['date'].apply(default_days, args=[repayments, 15])
```

The result here is that it's counting the number of rows with due_date 15 days before each specified date. I need it to sum the amounts instead of count the rows

Comment: Can you show us your code so far?

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide [your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) It is not clear, what you are asking for and we can't guess your data structure.

Comment: @Piinthesky I have updated the code to include a sample of the data structure and what the results would look like. I apologize for not including this, this is my first question on stackoverflow

Comment: @vektor I have included some of my code. I think a small change here could do the trick

Comment: The result to my code is that it's counting the number of rows with due_date 15 days before each specified date. I need it to sum the amounts instead of count the rows

Comment: So, you are looking for something like [`pandas.cumsum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. Thanks everyone for your advice!

```
def default_days(date, outstanding_loans, days):
    m = (outstanding_loans['repayment_date'] <= date - pd.DateOffset(days))
    y = outstanding_loans[m]
    c = y.amount_principal.sum()
    return c

dates = pd.date_range('2015-11-30',pd.to_datetime('today'), freq='M')

defaultt = pd.DataFrame({'date':dates})

defaultt['15 days'] = defaultt['date'].apply(default_days, args=[repayments, 15])
```